# get consecutive records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table structure as following

```
ID           user_id         win 
1              1               1 
2              1               1 
3              1               0 
4              1               1 
5              2               1 
6              2               0 
7              2               0 
8              2               1 
9              1               0 
10             1               1 
11             1               1 
12             1               1 
13             1               1
14             3               1
```

I wants to get consecutive wins(win=1) for each users in mysql.like for user_id=1, it should return 4(record id 10,11,12,13), for user_id=2(record id=5), it should return 1.

I can do that in php after retriving record for each user but I don't know how I can do it using query to mysql.

Also what would be better in term of performance, using php or mysql. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: no, as 1,2,4,9 is not consecutive. The user_id=1 loses in record_id=3

Comment: well 1,2 are consecutive wins, do you want the longest winning streak ?

Comment: yes, indeed. sorry, I don't mention it in question. I wants longest winning streak.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you've managed to get the other query to work but here's my attempt, definetly working - [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6d349/5) to prove it.

```
set @x=null;
set @y=0;

select sub.user_id as user_id,max(sub.streak) as streak
from
(
select 
case when @x is null then @x:=user_id end,
case 
when win=1 and @x=user_id then @y:=@y+1 
when win=0 and @x=user_id then @y:=0 
when win=1 and @x<>user_id then @y:=1
when win=0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=0
end as streak,
@x:=user_id as user_id
from your_table
) as sub
group by sub.user_id
```

How to get it to work on a PHP page and testing to see you're getting the right results is underneath, I have also optimized the query a bit:

```
mysql_query("set @y=0");
$query=mysql_query("select sub.user_id as user_id,max(sub.streak) as streak
from
(
select
case 
when win=1 and @x=user_id then @y:=@y+1 
when win=0 and @x=user_id then @y:=0 
when win=1 and @x<>user_id then @y:=1
when win=0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=0
end as streak,
@x:=user_id as user_id
from your_table
) as sub
group by sub.user_id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
print_r($row);}
```

Comment: hi, executing this query using the mysql_query function in php is not returning anything, while this works fine on phpmyadmin. Any suggestion for this.Thanks

Comment: @PriteshGupta Hi, I've edited my post to include how I've got it to work on a php page I made.

Comment: @PriteshGupta Also before anyone else says it: mysql_query is depreciated now and you should be using either mysqli or PDO, but I've done the code in mysql_query since I don't expect you to change everything all of a sudden. But it's worth learning about - personally I'd recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: thanks of lot for helping me here and pointing out the I should use PDO.Thanks

Comment: There is one problem in this query that if record of users are not consecutive then it will give wrong result. For example, if userid=1 has 2 consecutive wins then next 2 record of user_id=2 then after this if user_id wins again , it will start count from 1, while it should start from 3. so I think I needs to iterate for each user to get consecutive win by that user. Any more suggestion on this will be good.

Answer (score 4):

Inner query counts each streak.  Outer query gets the max per user.  Query is untested (but based on one that works)

```
set @user_id = null;
set @streak = 1;

select user_id, max(streak) from (
  SELECT user_id, streak,
    case when @user_id is null OR @user_id != user_id then @streak := 1 else @streak := @streak + 1 end as streak_formula,
    @user_id := user_id,
    @streak as streak
  FROM my_table
) foo
group by user_id
```

Comment: I am testing it. will let you know soon.

Comment: I am not able to run it for mysql. Could u kindly explain this so may I correct the things I am doing wrong. I had replaced my_table by my table name. is another thing needs to be changed?

Comment: What error do you get?  Does my_table contain a column named user_id?